# Read tweets using PHP

Tags: php, twitter

I have a small problem with my tweets script. But for some reason, I don't know what the error could be. This is the error it gives me:

```
$url    = "http://www.twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/{$username}.xml?count={$number}";
$tweets = file_get_contents($url);
$feed   = new SimpleXMLElement($tweets);

function time_stamp($date){
if (empty($date)){
    return "No date provided";
}
```

and on the index.php page, it'll show this code:

```
<?php
    $username = "user";//your twitter username
    $number = 3;//number of tweets
    include ("{$dir}/php/tweets.php");
?>
```

Do you guys know what it is that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hey, did you manage to get this working? Accept if it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `file_get_contents()`

Try:

```
$url    = "http://www.twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/{$username}.xml?count={$number}";
$feed   = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

Also, twitter made some changes not too long ago so your URL needs to look like this:

`$url    = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/{$username}.xml?count={$number}";`

Check [this](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/11694) discussion.

Comment: it looks like it worked a bit because it shows part of the stuff at razefm.com. However i get this error: http://screensnapr.com/v/YciDsu.png

Comment: Updated. Try the new URL I posted.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **JSON** easy and faster than **XML**

And to get content you can use

**Curl**      =>   Faster

or

**File_get_contents**

Url

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name={screenname}&count={count}
```

like this

```
<?php
  $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=abdullaheid&count=3'

  $x = file_get_contents( $url ) ; // Using file get contents

  $object = json_decode( $x ) ;
  $array = (array) $object    ;

  print_r( $array ) ;

?>
```

Comment: It would be nice of you to explain why Curl would be faster?